# Android навигационное приложение mapkit. Найти расстояние по дороге между точками

Tags: android, mapkit

делаю навигационное приложение с помощью mapkit. Нужно найти расстояние между точками по дороге, не по прямой, нужно учитывать саму дорогу. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: желательно приложить код какой-то, а то так сложно сказать определенно :(

Comment: Вот вам [Mapbox Navigation API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/navigation/). Разбирайтесь.